# Bounds on limsup and liminf

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limsup-and-liminf

Let $ \{x_n \}$ be an arbitrary sequence of real numbers and $A \in \mathbb R$. How prove that:

1. If there exists $ K \in \mathbb N $ such that for all $ n> K $, we have that $ a_n \leq A $ then $$\lim_{n\to \infty}\sup a_n\leq A.$$
2. If for all $K \in \mathbb N$, there exists $ n_k> K $ such that $ a_ {n_k} \leq A $, then $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\inf a_{n}\leq A.$$

I have tried but I have not achieved anything, I do not even know where to start.  Someone help me with one and I make the other or some suggestion that allows me to do both items...

Definition: Let $ \{s_n \} $ be a sequence of real numbers, and in the set of numbers $ x $ (in the extended system of real numbers) such that $s_ {n_k} \to x $ for some sub-sequence $  \{s_ {n_k} \} $.  This set E contains all the subsequence limits, possibly the numbers $ \pm \infty $.  Let's do $$s^*=\sup E$$ $$s_*=\inf E$$ the numbers $ s^* $ and $ s_* $ are called the upper and lower limits of $ \{s_n \} $ and the notation is used $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sup E=s^*$$ $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\inf E=s_*$$

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Let me amplify the comment above.  Please **edit the question** to let us know what you've tried, where you're stuck, and how much background you have.  For example, what definitions are you using for $\lim \sup$ and $\lim \inf$?  Questions that don't demonstrate some independent effort to solve the problem usually aren't well received here.

Comment: Start with the definition of the terms you're using.  What are they?  Again, put this information in the question.  Also let us know how much background you have.  I suggest you hurry or this question will attract more votes to close.

Comment: In English, this says that if all but finitely many terms of the sequence are no greater than $A$, then the $\lim \sup$ is also no greater than $A$, and if infinitely many terms are no greater than $A$ (a weaker condition), then the $\lim \inf$ is likewise no greater than $A$.

Comment: If considering the definition doesn't help, try playing with some concrete examples to see what's going on.